# Is it advisable to remove complaints from closed questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

Today I've seen a case of a co-user repeatedly removing a complaint from a closed question, going like this:

```
PS: THIS IS NOT A REAL QUESTION....LOL? Sigh...some people!!
```

While this is not an elaborate form of formulating one's disapproval, I think it's still valid protest and should be left as is, especially because:

- The question is closed and will not be viewed by a lot of users anymore (the chance of the question being improved and re-opened seems questionable, given OP's unwillingness to accept the close decision)
- The usual arguments regarding the removal of clutter from the text don't apply any longer when a question is closed

Should we remove these kinds of statements or leave them there, maybe in the name of freedom of speech?

Comment: Burn 'em all! They waste space if nothing else. The question's been closed not deleted.

Comment: @M.Babcock: What space do they waste? And what purpose does it serve to remove them?

Comment: The question does still occupy space in the StackExchange servers. It's insignificant I know, but still more than it deserves. If you want to complain about your question being closed... comments are not the way to do it.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Well the first part is really not an argument. It still takes up space (even more so) after being edited. The second one is more valid, but not all users understand or want to take part in the whole "philosophy" around SO, Meta and all

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CSRV2.png =)

Comment: Fun fact: "LOL?" is *also* not a real question.

Comment: That's my point!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anything that doesn't contribute directly to the question is subject to being edited out, either by the community or by a moderator.

This principle includes such things as signatures, taglines, "thanks," and so forth, so the kind of editorial comments like the one you found certainly qualify.

Answer (score 6):

> The question is closed and will not be viewed by a lot of users anymore (the chance of the question being improved and re-opened seems questionable, given OP's unwillingness to accept the close decision)

So? It won't be viewed by *a lot* of users, but it **will still be viewed by some**.

> The usual arguments regarding the removal of clutter from the text don't apply any longer when a question is closed

The question is still a question and it's still visible, so any clutter that is not related to the question at hand should still be removed like anywhere else. While it is true that a lot of users won't bother if they know it's likely to be deleted, it's still a gesture of merit. If the user is continually adding it back in after it's been removed, they are in fact still abusing the system.

Some people don't realize that just because a question is closed doesn't mean it's life is over. If the OP spent the time **improving** the question so that it was deemed to be a valid question for the site, then it could be reopened and answered. Instead, they're sitting there adding a useless notice to the post over and over, which is eventually going to attract moderator attention when the system flags it for rollback wars. Then they're *really* going to get in trouble.

Not only that, but every time that post gets edited to add in that worthless line, it also gets bumped to the homepage for recent activity, and more people are looking at a worthless question that is closed. It's taking up space on their screens when it shouldn't need too.